# Maximising a quadratic function under a constraint

Tags: optimization, determinant, lagrange-multiplier, binomial-distribution, constraints

Let
$$f:[0,1]^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~~(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i(1-x_i).$$

Now fix $\overline{x}\in[0,1]$. I would like to show that under the constraint
$$\overline{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,$$
$f$ is maximised by
$$x_1 = \ldots = x_n = \overline{x}.$$
Background: The variance of a generalised Binomial distribution with given mean probability of success is maximised if all probabilities of success are equal.

I tried using a Lagrange multiplier and bordered Hessian, but I don't understand the result:

Consider
$$L_{\overline{x}}(\lambda, x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i(1-x_i) - \lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-n\overline{x}\right).$$

Then the extended gradient and bordered Hessian of $L$ are given by (I think)
$$\nabla L_{\overline{x}}(\lambda, x) = \left(n\overline{x}-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,1-2x_1-\lambda,\ldots,1-2x_n-\lambda\right)$$
and
$$HL_{\overline{x}}(\lambda, x) = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&-1&\cdots&-1\\
-1&-2&0&\cdots&0\\
-1&0&-2&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&-2&0\\
-1&0&\cdots&0&-2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, curiously, through Laplace's theorem, I think the determinant of $H$ has alternating sign with $n$:
$$\mbox{det}(HL_{\overline{x}}(\lambda, x)) = -n\cdot(-2)^{n-1}$$

Are the conjecture and my approach reasonable? If so, is there a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show your claim in an elementary way as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i(1-x_i)
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 \\
& = & n\bar x - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x + \bar x)^2 \\
& = & n\bar x - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)^2  + 2\bar x\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)}_{=0} + n\bar x^2 \right)\\
& = & n\bar x -\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar x)^2  - n\bar x^2\\
& \leq & n(\bar x - \bar x^2) \mbox{ with equality for } x_i =\bar x \mbox{ for } i=1,\ldots , n
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: A very good answer, thanks. I just realised that you can get something similar through Cauchy-Schwarz. However, I still wonder what the problem with the constraint-based approach is - any ideas?

Comment: @Mau314 If you look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian under "Generalizations" you will see, that for a local maximum the principal minors from $3 \times 3$ up to $n\times n$ need to have alternating sign. So, this is exactly what you obtained.

Comment: @Mau314 But since this is so far a local maximum, you need an extra argument to conclude that it is a global maximum on $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right, thanks - too stupid to read the article properly... . Anyway, I'm glad to be aware of your nice solution now!